# Write intervals of the form $[a,b[$ using intervals of the form $]c,d]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I've seen a lot of posts about writing open intervals using closed intervals, but is it possible to write intervals of the form $[a,b[, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ using the union, intersection or difference of intervals $]c,d],c,d \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\cap_n \cup_m (a-\frac 1 n, b-\frac 1 n]$.

Comment: I assume you meant $b- \frac{1}{m}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about it.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the help!